# Sharing folder between Owncloud and Plex

Tags: permissions, plex, owncloud-server

I have a working owncloud and plex installation. Now I want to have a shared folder between these two.
I have created a folder /Music and have added it as external storage in owncloud and as library in plex.

My problem is that I cant set the permissions on the folder to get both working.
Owncloud uses the user www-data and plex uses the user plex.
If I set `chown -R www-data:www-data /Music` only Owncloud can read and write files. If I set `chown -R plex:plex /Music` only Plex can read and write files.

But now I have added the user plex to the group www-data with `usermod -a -G www-data plex` and groups plex gives me `plex: plex plugdev www-data`
Then I changed the permission with `chmod -R 775 /Music`

But Plex cant access the folder on the webapp. If I type `sudo -u plex touch /Music/newfile` it works. But the webapp only works if I set the owner and group of the folder to plex. I have tried to add the www-data user to the group plex but than owncloud cant access the folder. Owncloud seems to work only if the user and group is set to www-data.

Answer (score 0):

It's ACL permissions..

for example:

```
setfacl g:plex:rwx /path/
setfacl g:www-data:rwx /path/
```